# Java / Android - Comparing data between custom class ArrayList and custom class Adapter

Tags: java, android

Okay, new question... I now need to compare the address field from every sms in the inbox with the adress field from every sent sms, to see if there is a match (an exchange of messages with a certain address)

Custom class arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Sms> arraySms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
```

The custom class adapter is:

```
SmsAdapter adapter = new SmsAdapter(this, arraySms);
```

I have made the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
{
    if (adapter.getItem(i).getType().equals("2"))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < getAllInboxSms().size(); j++)
        {
            if (getAllInboxSms().get(j).getAddress().equals(adapter.getItem(i).getAddress()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Yeah!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"No!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No equals 2!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it always returns "No equals 2!". 
Again, I don't know if my code is right...

I thinking about this, and instead of all this i could "simply" search the inbox, get each address, and then filter the sent box with each address, to see if there is a reply to the message.
Anyone has any clue?

Comment: What is the type and value of `adapter.getItem(i).getType()` ?

Comment: How a type would match "2" !!?

Comment: @Pedram if `getType()` returns a `String`, why not.

Comment: Yes it returns a string. Values can be 1 or 2

Comment: Paste rest of your code, adapter and your model class

Comment: Hello @Pedram, I have moved from this question to another one, you can see it here and help me if you can.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478578/comparing-string-of-custom-class-within-two-arrays/30481449?noredirect=1#comment49063720_30481449

Thank you.

Comment: @Pedram or you can access it here. https://github.com/RafaFCM/ReadSMSApp